# method return generic func c#

Tags: c#, linq, generics

Is it possible to return a generic Func from a method?
What I want to do is something like the GetSortFunc below.

```
public class Example
{
    private List<MyObject> _objects;
    public Example()
    {
        _objects = new List<MyObject>
                        {
                            new MyObject {Id = 1, Name = "First", Value = 100.0},
                            new MyObject {Id = 2, Name = "Second", Value = 49.99},
                            new MyObject {Id = 3, Name = "Third", Value = 149.99}
                        };
    }

    public void Sort(SomeEnum sortOptions)
    {
        _objects = _objects.OrderBy(GetSortFunc(sortOptions));
    }

    private Func<MyObject, TKey> GetSortFunc(SomeEnum sortOptions)
    {
        switch (sortOptions)
        {
            case SomeEnum.First:
                return x => x.Id;
            case SomeEnum.Second:
                return x => x.Name;
            case SomeEnum.Third:
                return x => x.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

The SomeEnum and MyObject looks like this:

```
public enum SomeEnum
{
    First,
    Second,
    Third
}

public class MyObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

Is this possible to do or am I on the wrong track?

Comment: yep it is possible :-)

Comment: Looks like it would be a lot less work for you to just use `.OrderBy()` as it is

Comment: First of all, this is possible, secondly, whether it is possible or not, you can compile your code and find out.

Comment: @Alex yeah of course it would be easier to just call OrderBy in this example, but I'm going to have to switch between OrderBy and OrderByDescending in my implementation and don't want a big mess of if/else and/or switch statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way fix your function change it like

```
private Func<MyObject, object> GetSortFunc(SomeEnum sortOptions)
{
    switch (sortOptions)
    {
        case SomeEnum.First:
            return x => x.Id;
        case SomeEnum.Second:
            return x => x.Name;
        case SomeEnum.Third:
            return x => x.Value;
        default:
            return x => x.Id;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's so obvious! I feel a bit stupid now for not thinking of this :)

Comment: Seems to work. I think the runtime can determine that the object is actually of type int/string/double

Comment: I didn't know this would work. It seems to try to cast to IComparable or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the return type will vary with the type of `TKey`. Also, the type parameters of `OrderBy` will vary. I suggest you just duplicate the `OrderBy` calls:

```
IEnumerable<MyObject> ApplySortOrder(IEnumerable<MyObject> items, SomeEnum sortOptions)
{
    switch (sortOptions)
    {
        case SomeEnum.First:
            return items.OrderBy(x => x.Id);
        case SomeEnum.Second:
            return items.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
        case SomeEnum.Third:
            return items.OrderBy(x => x.Value);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, make `GetSortFunc` return `delegate` and call `OrderBy` dynamically:

```
private Delegate GetSortFunc(SomeEnum sortOptions)
{
    switch (sortOptions)
    {
        case SomeEnum.First:
            return new Func<MyObject, int>(x => x.Id);
        case SomeEnum.Second:
            return new Func<MyObject, string>(x => x.Name);
        case SomeEnum.Third:
            return new Func<MyObject, int>(x => x.Value);
    }
}

//...

Enumerable.OrderBy(_objects, (dynamic)GetSortFunc(sortOptions));
```

This would pick the right overload at runtime.

Comment: Thanks! I'll probably go with the second example as I'm going to have to switch between OrderBy and OrderByDescending which would make the first approach a bit messy

Comment: The compiler doesn't like the dynamic approach, says that extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched

Comment: Call it like this: `Enumerable.OrderBy(items, ...)`. The two little problems mentioned in the comments here are just details. I did not test the code. The idea works.

Answer (score 2):

A generic `Func`, or any other generic type, can only be returned from context which has a declared generic parameter.  This generic parameter needs to exist on either the method or one of the containing types of the method.  In this case there is no generic parameter hence the code cannot function

This is really not a great example of a function that should be generic though.  If it were generic it would need to look something like this

```
private Func<MyObject, TKey> GetSortFunc<TKey>(SomeEnum sortOptions) 
{
    switch (sortOptions)
    {
        case SomeEnum.First:
            return x => (TKey)(object)x.Id;
        case SomeEnum.Second:
            return x => (TKey)(object)x.Name;
        case SomeEnum.Third:
            return x => (TKey)(object)x.Value;
    }
}
```

All that ugly casting exists because the C# compiler can't find an existing conversion between `int` and `string` and the `TKey` parameter (because it could be literally any type).  Also it won't work unless the type of the property matches `TKey` which is generally a sign of code that can't be generic.